# What's the difference between omitting `self` in method definition or not?

Tags: ruby, syntax, methods, self

I know `self` is the receiver of the method calling.
But I do not know if there is not `self` in method definition.

code example:

```
class One
  def kk
    "kk"
  end
  def self.kkk
    "kkk"
  end
end

puts One.new.kk
puts One.kkk
```

Why do I need to use `new` method for `One` used like `One.new.kk` ?

Comment: Hover over the "ruby" tag and then click on the ["info" link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info). Enjoy (reading the online resources)! Needing a "new" object is a very common task in many OOP languages and is covered in tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.kkk` here defines a class method of `One`. As you know, `self` is the receiver. In the context here it is the `One` class.

And `One.new` returns an instance of class `One`. `kk` is an instance method that only called by an instance.

Comment: So, if I do not define a method with `self.`, then it is a instance method, does this right ? (And does this have a name for it ?)

Comment: Yes. And I'm not sure what you mean "does this have a name for it". I recommend reading some books or posts about OOP languages. These are the basic concepts.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Demo2
  def self.method1(a)
    p a.is_a? Demo2
  end

  def method2(b)
    p b.to_s
  end

end
a=Demo2.new
# here, if you type a.... wait for hint, you just can only get method2()
# just because it class self.
a.method2('123')
Demo2.method1(a)
p Demo2   # this is a class
p a       # this a class instance


>'123'   
>true
>Demo2
>#<Demo2:0x290d768>
```

I think this simple code can make you clear, I don't talk *OOP* with you, that's so boring!^_^